# classify all surface in which $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ can be embedded.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Using the fact that $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ are not planar, classify all surface in which $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ can be embedded.

I know $K_5$ can be embedded into a torus. Can anyone give a hint for the  classification?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can both be embedded in a torus and hence any higher genus surface. One way to see this is that they can each be drawn in the plane with one crossing. By adding a little tube to the plane as a bridge that one arc can use to cross the other, and adding a point at infinity, we get a genus one surface.

Are you also interested in nonorientable surfaces? Instead of adding an extra tube as above, you can add one that starts above the plane and ends below it, giving that these two graphs embed in a Klein bottle. This implies they embed in every nonorientable surface except possibly the projective plane. Do you know whether these graphs embed in the projective plane?

**Edit:** They do embed in the projective plane, which we think of as the quotient of the disk by gluing points on opposite sides. Note that in the $K_{3,3}$ picture below, the top edge which exits the disk on the right connects to the bottom one on the left and vice versa.[image]

Comment: So, $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ are embeddable all connected compact surfaces without boundary.

Comment: @ErginSuer Except the sphere!